# Split Blogger Post Body into halves

Tags: javascript, json, blogger

Please I am a blogger and programmer, I have been trying to split the `<data:post.body/>` into halves. I noticed the article itself resides within this tag. Please how can I go about it, my main aim for this is to insert Google ads within the article body.

Comment: First, you need to define what _exactly_ does it mean to "split body in half".

Comment: What I mean is taking the entire body text and breaking it into separate sections so as to embed ads in between them.

Comment: Yes, that's what you said before. What I meant is: if you're going to put this into code, you need to understand what _exactly_ you are going to do. Splitting body string in two equal halves is trivial, but what if the split point is in the middle of the sentence? Middle of the word? Is this something you want to handle? If so, your splitting algorithm will need changes.

Comment: Thanks, I rather not do that...

Comment: You abandoned the idea of splitting altogether? :)

Comment: yes please!!! Thank you.